# How would I input data into an array from user? I'm using accessors and mutators

Tags: java, arrays

Okay. Here's my first page with the accessors and mutators

```
public class TimeCard {
    private int employeeNum;
    private String[] clockInTimes = new String[14];
    private String[] clockOutTimes = new String[14];
    private float[] decimalClockIn = new float[14];
    private float[] decimalClockOut = new float[14];
    private float[] timeElapsed =  new float[14];

public String[] getClockInTimes()
    {  
         return clockInTimes;
    }

    public void setClockInTimes(String[] value)
   {  
         clockInTimes = value;
   }
}
```

My second class acessessing those set/get arrays.
How would I ask for user input for each array subscript 0-13?

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    TimeCard josue = new TimeCard();

    System.out.println("Enter Monday Clock In Times:");
    //not sure if this is right?
    josue.setClockInTimes[0](reader.next());
  }
}
```

By the way I need to do it like this because teacher wants it this way. I'm just not really sure how to get user input and put it into an array using an object class.

Comment: You probably want to do something like have your setter take an index *and* a value. Currently, the setter overwrites the whole array.

Comment: how would that look like? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Try putting the Scanner in a for loop and setting the array's index to the for loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably start by changing your setter to take an index and a value, so something like this:

```
public void setClockInTime(int day, String clockInTime) {
    this.clockInTimes[day] = clockInTime; // note you don't need to write "this," but it's clearer that this is a member field
}
```

And then in your main method:

```
for (int i=0;i<14;i++) {
    String input = <get input>
    josue.setCliockInTime(i, input);
}
```

Now you can set one value at a time, and that should let you populate all of your fields.